# Using graphics.py on IDLE doesn't work at all

Tags: python

Using 10.14 Mojave and Python 3.7. The only things I have done are following the sys.path way and the graphics (copy-pasted from a site to IDLE) are in the right folder and also trying to write from graphics import * and import graphics on IDLE. Sometimes nothing happens, just next line of >>> ready after pressing enter and other times I get an error message:

"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    from graphics import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/graphics.py", line 11
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

If I just get the >>> and try to - for example - drawLine(0,100) code, nothing happens. openWindow(), still, nothing happens.

Do I need to use Terminal to do something? Have I forgotten a step? How do I get the graphics? There are two sets I need and neither are working. Haven't been able to find anything that works online.

Comment: Does it work in the terminal either?

Comment: How do i do that? What do i need to write on terminal?

Comment: You can create a .py file containing your code and run that from the command terminal (IDLE also allows you to edit and run python files without having to use the REPL environment)

Comment: So i have a .py file of the code but how do I install it though terminal or what do you mean? I'm very new to this...

Comment: Well if your system paths are set up correctly you should be able to just navigate to the file using the terminal and type `python <filename>` to run it

Comment: it is in correct place for idle to find it but terminal says: can't open file 'graphics': [Errno 2] No such file or directory